# Migrating Xamarin.forms app to Android 12 leads to Prism doesn't find the registered viewmodels

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, prism

I have one Xamarin.Forms app with prism 8.1.96 that works great, but when I try to update the Android SDK to have Android 12 (SDK V31), I receive a blank screen and a message that says:

"An error occurred while resolving the page. This is most likely the result of invalid XAML or other type initialization exception."

Since nothing have been changing on XAML side, what can I do to fix this problem?

Comment: Do you have the lastest version of Prism in your application?

Comment: yes, actually I typed wrong, the latest version is 8.1.97.

Comment: Can you show me the line of code that throws the exception and the stacktrace?

Comment: Sometimes after an update that causes problems, it helps to delete `bin` and `obj` folders.

Comment: I believe you need add a `try-catch`  with a breakpoint in code-behind `InitializeComponent` to see what exact the root cause for the blank screen.

Comment: I had to rewrite all the project because it maybe was a namespace problem.

Answer (score 0):

Without code it's impossible to say what the error is outright. The error message you're referencing can only come from the NavigationException. It's important to look at the inner exception. It likely has a ContainerResolutionException. If you get the Inner Exception and cast it to it's proper type you can call the GetErrors method which would let you get a list back of types/errors... typically the last type/error is the root cause of your issue.

```cs
var result = await navigationService.NavigateAsync("SomePath");
if(result.Exception is not null && result.Exception.InnerException is ContainerResolutionException cre)
{
    var errors = cre.GetErrors();
    var root = errors.Last();
    System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
}
```

Comment: the strange part of it is with the 7.0 version running with android 10, no problem occurs. If I try to update the packages for the last version it crashes.
I've checked my project and in the "core" project we have the .Forms name in her namespace. I've downloaded the prism extension for VS and created the project again using the vs model, after a long work of re doing the project without the wrong namespace it worked.